# Combine observables in the order of availability of its elements

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to build an operator like `s.startWith(x)`, but conditional one - let's call it `s.startWithIfNothingAvailable(x)`. I want it to prefix stream with an `x` only if `s` *has no elements available* at the moment of subscription.

Let me illustrate the idea with an example.

`s` is a stream of reports from server.

- If there is no report arrived yet, I want to prefix `s` with an empty one - just to update ui with something.
- If `s` contains something(perhaps some reports were cached) prefixing `s` will result in rendering empty report and then non empty one. I would like to avoid such blinking.

I think the other way of solving that is to use something like `.concat` but which order observables by availability of its elements.

`Observable.concatFirstAvailable(serverReport, emptyReport)`, if `serverReport` has no elements yet - switch to `emptyReport` and than get back to waiting on `serverReport`.

Comment: The problem is "at the moment" which is hard to interpret: cold sources could be empty or timeout before they send their first item; hot sources may be empty, replay or simply emit the next item a bit later. So you either want `switchIfEmpty` or `timeout()` or perhaps a `mergeWith` where the other source emits a special item after some delay and can be ignored if it doesn't arrive first.

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry for not being clear. Observable in my example is hot and infinite. By saying _no elements available_ I mean that observable is not completed yet, but it also has no elements to send right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could merge with a delayed special report item:

```
// imitate infinite hot service
PublishSubject<Report> service = PublishSubject.create();

// special report indicating the service has no reports
Report NO_REPORT = new Report();

AtomicBoolean hasValue = new AtomicBoolean();

service
// we'll need the main value for both emission and control message
.publish(main ->
     // this will keep "listening" to main and allow a timeout as well
     main.mergeWith(
         // signal the empty report indicator
         Observable.just(NO_REPORT)
         // after some grace period so main can emit a real report
         .delay(100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
         // but if the main emits first, don't signal the empty report
         .takeUntil(main)
     )
)
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.subscribe(report -> {
     if (report == NO_REPORT) {
         // even if this onNext is serialized, NO_REPORT may get emitted
         if (!hasValue.get()) {
             // display empty report
         }
     } else {
         // this indicates a NO_REPORT should be ignored onward
         hasValue.set(true);
         // display normal report
     }
}, error -> {  /* show error */ })

Thread.sleep(200); // Thread.sleep(50)
service.onNext(new Report());
```

Comment: Didn't know about `takeUntil`! Implemented solution based on your answer and your previous comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your request correctly, then you could maybe use [startWith()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/startwith.html) and then [sample()](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html)

e.g. with a sample time of 50ms. When no report arrives within the first 50ms, then the `startWith` element will be used and you render the empty state. Otherwise, the latest report will be used.

`Sample` will also make sure that you don't try to update your UI too often: e.g. when the sever sends 2 reports within the 50ms, you don't want to render both, just the latest one.

Comment: Yeah, it kind of solves my problem - `Observable.interval(100, 900, MILLISECONDS).startWith(42).sample(500, MILLISECONDS, true)` omits `42`, but there are couple of problems with that solution. First, server stream is already throttled, additional `sample` will complicate things further. Second, I would like to avoid initial delay. Anyway, thank you for an answer!